# OpenCV4 can't initialize GTK backend

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <raspicam_cv.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace raspicam;

Mat frame;
void Setup (int argc, char **argv, RaspiCam_Cv &Camera)
{
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  ( "-w",argc,argv,360 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,  ( "-h",argc,argv,240 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, ( "-br",argc,argv,50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_CONTRAST ,( "-co",argc,argv,50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_SATURATION,  ( "-sa",argc,argv,50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_GAIN,  ( "-g",argc,argv ,50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FPS,  ( "-fps",argc,argv,0));
}    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
    Setup(argc, argv, Camera);
    cout<<"Connecting to Camera"<<endl;
    if(!Camera.open())
    {
       cout<<"Failed to connect";
       return -1;   
    }
    cout<<"Camera ID= "<<Camera.getId()<<endl;
    Camera.grab();
    Camera.retrieve(frame);
    
    imshow("frame", frame);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

error:
Connecting to Camera
Camera ID= 00000000b7f66138
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(4.5.0-pre) /home/pi/opencv/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:624: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'

Aborted

(program exited with code: 134)

Comment: This does not describe the problem and is not related to any programming topic.(The error literally means GTK cannot be initialized and that means X11 cannot be initialized.) Why is it plus voted?